# Consolidate Results from multiple test projects in a solution VSTest

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework, vstest

Right now I have a solution which has 3 Unit Test Projects in Visual Studio 2017 (4.6.2).

I have created TestCategories and executing the tests using command prompt based on TestCategories (Single Test Category/Mulitple Test Categories by using "&" operation in command).

I made a list of the TestResults, and keep adding the result to the list in TestCleanup method in each individual project. This TestResult list is global and can be accessed across all 3 Test Projects.

Once completed, in the Assembly Cleanup I am writing it to an Excel File and mailing it through to an email group in the organisation.

When I do this, I am getting 3 mails from 3 Test Projects.

To avoid this I added the mailing code in only 1 Test Project and make sure I run a test from that TestProject (even though I don't need that test to run).

Now, my problem is:
Suppose I have 3 TestProjects A, B & C, and I have the mailing logic in Assembly Cleanup in TestProject C.
1. Like an AssemblyCleanup, do we have a place where we know that all the A or B or C TestProjects are completed execution of tests?
2. Suppose if I run tests in only in TestProject A, where I dont have the mailing logic, I am not getting the mails. (Since the mailing logic is available in a different project - C.)
3. If I add mailing logic to all 3 projects (A, B & C), it send me 3 mails. Which I have to consolidate manually.
4. If I have executed couple of tests from each assembly (A, B, C). How do I know in the Assembly cleanup that there are still some pending tests to be executed in assembly B or C? - Based on this I can execute the mailing logic, if there are still some tests to execute from other assemblies I'll skip it in the current assembly and leave that happen in B or C. Similarly I'll write the same logic in all 3 assemblies. By doing this, I'll get only 1 report for all tests in all 3 assemblies/projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use /Logger:trx options to get test results file.
Eg. `vstest.console a.dll b.dll /logger:trx`